# How can use emailyak to send or receive email in php?

Tags: php, email

I would like to use [Email Yak](http://www.emailyak.com/) to send and receive emails with PHP. Is this posssible? If so how would I go about it?

Comment: is it possible to pass a php file with emailyak url https://api.emailyak.com/v1/private_api_key/json/send/email/

Comment: Also is it possible to pass dynamic contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do this from PHP, but take a look at the ['Send Email' manual page](http://docs.emailyak.com/send-email.html) at the Email Yak project.

You will need to use [PHPs curl extension](http://uk.php.net/curl) to make the HTTP requests with the appropriate headers and PHPs native [`json_encode()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to serialise the data you are sending.

A really simple curl example from [jonasjohn.de](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm) to get you going:

> function curl_download($Url){
>
> ```
> // is cURL installed yet?
> if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
>     die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
> }
>
> // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
> $ch = curl_init();
>
> // Now set some options (most are optional)
>
> // Set URL to download
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
>
> // Set a referer
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");
>
> // User agent
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
>
> // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
>
> // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false =
> ```
>
> print)
>       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>
> ```
> // Timeout in seconds
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
>
> // Download the given URL, and return output
> $output = curl_exec($ch);
>
> // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
> curl_close($ch);
>
> return $output;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Email Yak uses GET, POST and JSON. Definitely you can integrate with PHP.

See http://docs.emailyak.com/ for more information.